# WebService callout failed

Tags: webservices, apex-webservice

This Error is coming. I am wondering what could be the possible issue. I have given permission to the objects.

> Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: use of the Metadata API requires a user with the
>   ModifyAllData permission faultcode=sf:INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS faultactor=

Comment: Is your apex class Global?

Comment: yes its global..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are performing operation with Metadata API.That requires Modify all data permission.

You should check the profile of the user that it has **Modify all data** permission or not.

[image]

Comment: what do you exactly mean by Modify all data permission? 
I didn't get it..

Comment: You can enable [Modify all data](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=What-does-the-Modify-All-Data-perm-actually-do-1326847422250&language=en_US) permission on the profile of the user.

Comment: thanks @Frodo 
problem is solved I wasn't passing the sessionid while redirecting to page...